# Travis CI build failed ./gradlew assemble

Tags: java, android, travis-ci

I'm trying to build project with Travis CI and Codecov, but I'm getting this error when I build with Travis CI

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
BUILD FAILED
Total time: 31.202 secs

The command "eval ./gradlew assemble" failed. Retrying, 2 of 3.
```

This is my `.travis.yml`

```
language: java

jdk:
  - oraclejdk8

sudo: required

before_install:
 - chmod +x gradlew

script:
  - ./gradlew clean build -i --continue

after_success:
  - bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash) -t myToken
```

I've read this a lot about `before_install` but it doesn't change anything...

Comment: ***SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.***

Comment: please don't downvote...I've already tried but nothing change..

Answer (score 4):

You should set your "language" to android in your `.travis.yml` file as described in the link below.

Referring to the Travis documentation here: [Building an Android Project](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/android/)

Answer (score 0):

You could try writing below line in travis file

jdk: openjdk8

You can check the difference between oracle JDK and Open Jdk though. It should not matter as both are licenced one from oracle and one from open GNU PL but if you want specific difference you could visit -https://www.baeldung.com/oracle-jdk-vs-openjdk

Answer (score -1):

I solved with this:

```
language: android
sudo: false

before_script:
  - echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t android-21 --abi armeabi-v7a
  - emulator -avd test -no-skin -no-audio -no-window &
  - android-wait-for-emulator
  - adb shell input keyevent 82 &

android:
  components:
    # Update Android SDK Tools
    - tools

    - build-tools-25.0.1
    - android-25

    # Support library
    - extra-android-support
    - extra-android-m2repository

jdk:
  - oraclejdk8

sudo: required

before_install:
 - chmod +x gradlew

after_success:
  - bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash) -t token
```